# How to find the "two norm" of the difference between two vectors

Tags: normed-spaces

I am using the Jacobi iterative method to estimate the solution to the system of equations $Ax=b$.

With an iterative solver you take an initial (educated) guess as to what your $x$ may be, this is considered $x_{0}$ .  After plugging in the vector $x_{0}$ into the algorithm you get the vector $x_{1}$  which can be plugged in just as $x_{0}$ was to get $x_{2}$  and so on.

Each answer is notably closer to the answer which I am successful in calculating, what I do not understand is when to stop making iterations.

One way to see that the estimate is actually getting closer to the actual answer $x$ is to plug in the new value for $x_{k+1}$ into the equation $Ax=b$ giving you $b_{new}$, where $b_{old}$ is the vector you get when plugging in the old value for $x_k$.

I wish to stop making iterations when the "two norm" of $|b_{new}-b_{old}|$ is less than a given tolerance lets say `.001` for the sake of the example.

Comment: What is your exact question? Is it the question in your title (that isn't anywhere in the body of your power)?

Comment: Basically how to find the two norm of a vector, by vector I mean a matrix with at least 1 row and only one column

Comment: Are you just asking for the definition of the norm?

Comment: @JessicaK, yes for the two norm when taking the absolute value of the difference of two vectors so basically the two norm of a vector.  I do not doubt that It is probably somewhat trivial I have just been unable to find a decent example or explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The $2$-norm of a vector is the length of the vector (or perhaps the square of the length of the vector; this notation isn't completely standardized).

More generally, a $p$-norm of a vector $x = (x_1, ..., x_k)$ usually refers to either
$$ \lvert x \rvert_p = \sqrt[p]{|x_1|^p + \ldots + |x_k|^p}$$
or
$$ {\lvert x \rvert_p}^p = |x_1|^p + \ldots + |x_k|^p.$$

Comment: So basically when $p=2$ I would first take the difference of the two vectors giving me a single vector, then take the square root of the sum of each term in that vector?

Comment: To rephrase, you are finding the length of the difference of the vectors. This is perhaps the most intuitive norm out there, as being "far away" is literally being *far away*.